# How do I setup a custom change_list in django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm working with django and I've got a list of object, not linked to the database as model, but, as the models, I want to show them in the admin pages (list and detail).

How can I do?

I tried to register a custom view that extends "admin/base.html" but is a that doesn't solve my problem:

```
def external_list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    ctx = {
        'sources' : []
    }

    for i in range(1,10):
        ctx['sources'].append({
            'id' : i,
            'name' : 'item name %d' % i
            })        

    return render(request, 'admin/external_list.html', ctx)

admin.site.register_view('external_list', external_list, 'External sources')
```

if I try to extend "admin/change_list.html" it doesn't works; it asks me for some specific fields of the models